# Stop other onclick events

Tags: javascript

If two `onclick` are on top of each other, i would like to know how to stop the second one from launching.

Example :

```
<div id="div1" onclick="alert('a');">
a
<div id="div2" onclick="alert('b');">
b
</div>
a
</div>
```

if click on div2, i would like to have only `alert(b)`, but NOT `alert(a)` afterwards.

FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/ae9av150/2/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<div id="div1" onclick="alert('a');">
a
<div id="div2" onclick="alert('b');event.stopPropagation();">
b
</div>
a
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="div1" onclick="alert('a');">
a
<div id="div2" onclick="event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble=true);alert('b');">
b
</div>
a
</div>
```

Reference: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing
for IE<9, you should use event.cancelBubble=true

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

```
window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("div2").onclick = function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
          alert('b');
        }

    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="div1" onclick="alert('a');">
        a
        <div id="div2">
            b
        </div>
        a
    </div>
```